# flexible patterns for a factor variable in order to subset a dataframe

Tags: r, regex, string

I have a dataframe called mydf, simplified as below:

```
mydf

var1                          var2
abc_color1_location1_number1  1000
xyz_color1_location1_number1  100
asd_color2_location2_number1  900
qwe_color1_location1_number2  200
sdf_color2_location1_number2  1100
qwerrrr_ahjkkk_asdfgggg       234  
sdf_color1_location2_number1  3577
abc_color1_location3_number1  86544
```

I want to subset the dataset flexibly based on var1
For example:

```
pattern <- c("abc", "color1", "number1")
newmydf <- mydf[grep(paste("_",paste(pattern,collapse="_|_"),"_",sep=""),mydf$var1,ignore.case=T),]
```

My expected result:

```
newmydf
var1                          var2
abc_color1_location1_number1  1000
```

However, the resulted dataframe was only being subset with pattern "abc" and "color1" only, while I want all patterns should be considered. Can anyone please help me in this case?

Many thanks in advance!

With kind regards,

Comment: Should the expected result include first and last row of mydf?

Comment: @tatxif I agree with you.

Comment: @BINewbies looks like you found Lyzander's answer most helpful. Consider accepting it (check mark to the left of the answer).

Answer (score 2):

If you want all the elements of `pattern` to be considered, then something like this might help:

```
pattern <- c("abc", "color1", "number1")
alltrue <- rowSums(sapply(pattern, function(x) grepl(pattern = x, mydf$var1))) == 3

mydf[alltrue, ]
#                          var1  var2
#1 abc_color1_location1_number1  1000
#8 abc_color1_location3_number1 86544
```

Essentially `sapply` will run `grepl` for each one of the pattern elements and then only use those ones where all grepls are `TRUE`.

Comment: That works great. I'd like to ask in case I want to set 
pattern <- c("abc", "sdf")

Comment: It would work just fine no matter how many elements `pattern` has.

Answer (score 0):

A solution uses `tidyverse` and `stringr`. `mydf2` is the final output.

The `find_match` is a user-defined function, which can return a vecotr with `TRUE` or `FALSE` to see if all the words in `pattern` are found.

By applying the `find_match` function, we can `filter` the data frame based on the results.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(stringr)

find_match <- function(Col, pattern){
  m <- map(pattern, str_detect, string = Col)
  names(m) <- paste("Word", pattern)
  m2 <- as_data_frame(m)
  results <- rowSums(m2) == length(pattern)
  return(results)
}

mydf2 <- mydf %>% filter(find_match(var1, pattern))
mydf2
                          var1  var2
1 abc_color1_location1_number1  1000
2 abc_color1_location3_number1 86544
```

#### Data Preparation

```
# Create mydf
mydf <- read.table(text = "var1                          var2
abc_color1_location1_number1  1000
                   xyz_color1_location1_number1  100
                   asd_color2_location2_number1  900
                   qwe_color1_location1_number2  200
                   sdf_color2_location1_number2  1100
                   qwerrrr_ahjkkk_asdfgggg       234  
                   sdf_color1_location2_number1  3577
                   abc_color1_location3_number1  86544",
                   header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

# Define the pattern
pattern <- c("abc", "color1", "number1")
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative approach is to `strsplit` on `_` and use `all(... %in% ...)`

```
keep <- sapply(strsplit(mydf$var1, "_"), function(x) all(pattern %in% x))
df[keep,]
```

Output

```
                          var1  var2
1 abc_color1_location1_number1  1000
8 abc_color1_location3_number1 86544
```

Data

```
df <- structure(list(var1 = c("abc_color1_location1_number1", "xyz_color1_location1_number1", 
"asd_color2_location2_number1", "qwe_color1_location1_number2", 
"sdf_color2_location1_number2", "qwerrrr_ahjkkk_asdfgggg", "sdf_color1_location2_number1", 
"abc_color1_location3_number1"), var2 = c(1000L, 100L, 900L, 
200L, 1100L, 234L, 3577L, 86544L)), .Names = c("var1", "var2"
), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -8L))

pattern <- c("abc", "color1", "number1")
```